# Speech Recognizer Offline Capability Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is it possible to create a grammar file for speech recognition and use SpeechRecognizer offline, like Cortana?

I only found Speech.Recognizer examples... it seems like Recognizer can use [`SpeechRecognitionEngine.loadGrammar()`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a). I wonder if something similar is possible on a Windows Phone?

Is it possible to use SpeechRecognizer offline with a grammar File? Or is it possible to use Cortana's ability to recognize Speech To Text offline?

Comment: I have the same question. I don't understand the downvoting. `recoWithoutUI.Grammars.AddGrammarFromList("myCommands", MyStringArrayWithCommands)` was my simple solution